# Multiple IF conditions on two fields ( one custom field and one pick list field) for a formula field, but getting error

Tags: formula

```
IF( AND( High_Profile__c = "True" ,ISPICKVAL(Priority,"P1")), "Msg1", 
IF( AND( High_Profile__c = "True" ,NOT (ISPICKVAL(Priority,"P1"))), "Msg2" ,
IF( High_Profile__c = "False" , "No")))
```

> Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3,
>   received 2

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to format such big formulas. Once you do it, you see, that you missed to pass one parameter to last `IF` condition: **"High Profile is neither false nor true"**. So, considering, that `High_Profile__c` isn't boolean

```
IF(
    AND(
        High_Profile__c = "True" ,
        ISPICKVAL(Priority, "P1")
    ),
    "Msg1", 
    IF(
        AND(
            High_Profile__c = "True" ,
            NOT(ISPICKVAL(Priority,"P1"))
        ),
        "Msg2" ,
        IF(
            High_Profile__c = "False",
            "No",
            "High Profile is neither false nor true"
        )
    )
)
```

---

your formula can be re-written in the following more readable way:

```
IF(
    High_Profile__c = "True",
    IF(
        ISPICKVAL(Priority, "P1"),
        "Msg1",
        "Msg2"
    ),
    IF(
        High_Profile__c = "False",
        "No",
        "High Profile is neither false nor true"
    )
)
```

---

if you can have `High_Profile__c`  as boolean (Checkbox) field type, this formula becomes very simple:

```
IF(
    High_Profile__c,
    IF(
        ISPICKVAL(Priority, "P1"),
        "Msg1",
        "Msg2"
    ),
    "No"
)
```

Comment: Thank you Oleksandr. I appreciate your quick response. I tired the last formula but got error : Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'IF()'. Expected Boolean, received Text